# Time not insert when other user create content drupal 7

Tags: datetime, drupal-7, timezone

Time is proper insert in database when i create content from country (india)
When other user create content country (Bharain) time is not insert in data base.
only date and timezone will insert. I have set Default time zone (Asia/Bharain) 
But i couldn't understand What is the reason behind this?

Comment: please check whether u have checked the option for individual users to use their timezone(its a check box option in the same place u set the default time zone)